# ¿Declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘exit’?

Tags: c++, c, linux, centos7

Tengo el siguiente código creado en `Konsole` de `CentOS7` en donde, como pueden ver, intento crear un proceso con la función/comando `fork()` y gestionar las diferentes circunstancias de usarla:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(){
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1){
                printf("Error al crear el proceso hijo\n");
                exit(0);
        }

        if(pid){
                printf("Proceso padre, el PID de mi hijo es %d\n", pid);
        }else{
                printf("Soy el hijo, ejecutando herramienta date\n");
                execve("bin/date", NULL, NULL);
        }
}
```

Al ejecutar `gcc test_fork.c` en `Konsole` de `Linux CentOS` aparece el siguiente error:

```
[vapaternina@localhost ~]$ gcc test_fork.c 
test_fork.c: En la función ‘main’:
test_fork.c:10:3: aviso: declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘exit’ [activado por defecto]
   exit(0);
   ^
```

Comment: Por cierto, la etiqueta `c++` no aplica a esta pregunta porque para `c++` el uso de una función no declarada es un error y no un warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

#### Declaración implícita

Por defecto, si nosotros no declaramos una función **pero si la usamos**, el 
compilador *asume* que la función tiene el siguiente *prototipo*:

```
int funcion( );
```

Lo cual equivale a:

> Una función que devuelve un `entero` y acepta **cualquier número de argumentos en cualquier orden**, inclusive **ningún** argumento.

#### Funciones internas

Algunos compiladores realizan optimizaciones en el código de una forma concreta: tienen disponible una suerte de *extensión* del lenguaje, de forma similar a como si fueran *palabras reservadas*, que *reemplazan* a ciertas funciones del propio lenguaje. El mensaje de error

> declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘exit’ [activado por defecto]

Te está diciendo justamente eso: el compilador **proporciona una función `exit( )`** propia. Esta forma de actuar facilita la optimización del código, puesto que el compilador contempla el uso de ciertas *palabras reservadas* adicionales con un comportamiento concreto y genera un código especial en esos casos.

#### Explicación

Ahora ya sabemos lo que sigifica el mensaje: el prototipo por defecto que genera el compilador (`int exit( )`) **entra en conflicto** con la extensión propia del compilador. Como dichas extensiones suelen ser compatibles con las funciones del lenguaje, la extensión tendrá el prototipo `void exit( int )`. Y ambas cosas **no son iguales**, de ahí el **aviso**.

#### Solución

Tienes varias opciones:

1. Declara tu mismo una función `exit( )`:

   ```
   void exit( int );

   int main( void ) {
     ...
   ```
2. Usa el archivo de cabecera correspondiente:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   ```
3. Deshabilita el uso de esa extensión concreta del compilador (en cuyo caso normalmente te generará el aviso de `función sin definir`):

   - `-fno-builtin`: Deshabilita **todas** las funciones internas.
   - `-fno-builtin-exit`: Deshabilita `exit( )` como función interna.

Answer (score 1):

El C hace una cosa "maravillosa" (modo irónico), y es que si llamas a una función que no estaba previamente declarada, en lugar de dar un error, se inventa para tí la declaración. Esta declaración "implícita" (inventada diría yo) usa siempre como tipo retornado `int` (porque sí), y como tipos de los parámetros los que hayas puesto en la invocación.

Así, por ejemplo, si encuentra esta invocación:

```
funcion_nueva(3, "Hola");
```

y esa función no estaba previamente declarada, se inventa la declaración:

```
int funcion_nueva(int, char *);
```

y sigue adelante. Esto puede estar bien, o puede estar mal. Si la función en cuestión (que normalmente estaría en una biblioteca u objeto externo) no responde a ese prototipo, puedes tener problemas en tiempo de ejecución.

Por otro lado, algunas de las funciones de la biblioteca estándar C son conocidas por el compilador. Aunque estas funciones estrictamente no son parte del lenguaje sino de su biblioteca estándar, `gcc` de algún modo trae de serie el conocimiento de cuál es el prototipo de estas funciones. Entre ellas `printf()`, `exit()`, etc.

Entonces tiene hace algo que roza la esquizofrenia :-) En tu código se encuentra la función `exit(0)`, y resulta que tal función no ha sido previamente declarada, por lo que inventa para ella la declaración:

```
int exit(int);
```

pero luego, como resulta que `gcc` "sabía" que esa función en realidad debería ser `void exit(int);` se encuentra con que la declaración implícita que él mismo se acaba de inventar, no coincide con lo que el sabía que debía salir, así que te da este aviso, cuyo significado es ahora más evidente:

```
aviso: declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘exit’ [activado por defecto] exit(0);
```

La solución consiste en declarar explícitamente cuál es el prototipo de `exit()`. Esa precisamente es la misión de un `#include <stdlib.h>` ya que dentro de ese fichero `.h` se hallan los prototipos de varias funciones típicas de la biblioteca estándar, `exit()` entre ellas.

Answer (score -1):

agregar `#include <stdlib.h>` a tu codigo fuente